# My View disappears... tableViewController load viewController, but the View shows black. Why?

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, xcode4.2, uitableview

Look this situation...

- My View disappears.

Why ???

http://www.4shared.com/photo/9XIMsP9a/AppConcDuvida.html

Answer (score 0):

Creating DetalhesViewController in code is unlikely to work correctly.

If you're going to use a storyboard and segues, then you should be making your connections there and configuring the new controller in prepareForSegue instead of didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: I saw that code in your first image.  Don't use that.  Make your connection in the **storyboard** and use `prepareForSegue:` instead.

Comment: Look this…

I need…

http://www.4shared.com/photo/bMhvRNgN/i_have_to_do_this_2.html

Comment: You seem to be saying that you want to use the wrong code in the wrong place but have it work anyway.  I don't know how to help with that.  [*shrug*]

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate your view controller from storyboard.

```
DetalhesViewController *detailViewController = [self.storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"controllerIdentifier"];
self.navigationController push:detailViewController animated:YES];
```